# Java code parser for the closure of method calls starting at a particular method

Tags: java, function, parsing, nested

I need to parse code of single java function collecting all the occurences of a particular string with regex (in the names of variables, string assignments, comments etc.) which sounds as a task of a simple text parser.

But the problem arises when I need to collect all the occurences also inside the closure of method calls starting at a particular method.

How can I implement a parser that traverse the closure of method calls starting at a particular method and collect all the occurences of a particular string?

So if I have a code:

```
public void A() {

    String abc = "$[LABEL_123]"
    B();        

}

public void B() {

    String def = "$[LABEL_456]"
    // $[LABEL_000]
    C();

}

public void C() {

    String ghi = "$[LABEL_789]"

}
```

For the function A I should have an array:

```
["$[LABEL_123]", $[LABEL_000], "$[LABEL_456]", "$[LABEL_789]"]
```

Comment: It's impossible without some constraints. If "nested function" can by only in same class then you can take java parser and find metho calls.

Comment: What if function may call functions that are in other java classes? I have functions that call "header" or "footer" functions that can be situated in different classes..

Comment: Just a small update: I don't want to write my own grammar parser (ANTLR or something similar), I'm almost sure exist a top-down parser for this purpose

Comment: You say "nested function", but these functions aren't nested. Do you mean "the closure of method calls starting at a particular method"?

Comment: Of course you can find third party parser. With several classes there are can be problems. Anyway you seems not experienced enough to implement solution that I think about

Comment: Yes, I should correct

Comment: A question arising in my head: WHY do you want to that? It looks a bit as if you want to implement some code checks or metaprogramming or something. Consider to use existing tools for your purpose. Maybe you can utilize Checkstype (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) or similar tool to get what you want? Analyzing source code by yourself might be overkill.